# Outlook 2013 too many devices synching with your account error

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

When I add an outlook.com account I get this error:

> Error Code: 0x80004005 Too many devices synching with your account

I definitely do not have multiple devices synching with this account... I searched online and it looks like this error has something to do with number of folders in the email. However, this is a fresh account. I only have the default folders in there.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This issue was resolved by Microsoft when it switched its public email from POP3 to Exchange ~2017ish, and due to this resolution, this issue is moot and should be closed.  The issue could only ever be fixed by Microsoft internally and is analogous to a question remaining open regarding a public DNS server being down... there's no substantive reason for this to remain open due to (1) the issue being an internal Microsoft one a user had no control over to resolve and (2) the issue was resolved by the switch to Exchange in lieu of POP3.

Answer (score 0):

Known issue with Microsoft. There is a forum post here which you should comment on which will allow MS to do some back end update to your account to resolve this issue.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/hotmail-sync/outlook-2013-error-too-many-devices-syncing-with/ee917ac5-a301-4196-a6f2-195d73d4196a

Answer (score 0):

This question should be closed as:

- Issue was resolved by Microsoft when it switched its public email from POP3 to  Exchange ~2017ish, with the issue severely spiking after Microsoft changed over to SSO.
- The issue was an internal one within Microsoft's POP3 servers that had to be manually fixed by Microsoft on a per account basis, which tended to affect users with larger email folder trees, and there was nothing an end-user could do to resolve the issue except wait for Microsoft to manually reset the connection count on the affected account.

AFAIK, this issue has not occurred since the switch from POP3 to Exchange.