# Outlook.com custom domain, Exchange ActiveSync too many connected devices

Tags: windows-8, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, outlook.com

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Outlook 2013 too many devices synching with your account error](https://superuser.com/questions/513389/outlook-2013-too-many-devices-synching-with-your-account-error)

I just setup Outlook.com to run on a custom domain. The web interface works well but when I connect it to Outlook 2013 I get the following error:

> There are too many devices syncing with this account. To sync using
>   Outlook, try removing another device that is connected with this
>   account such as a phone or another computer.
>
> File: outlook\pstprx\storeas\utils\airsyncstatuscodes.h Line: 88
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK FolderStatus: 177 To re-try press F9...   Error
>   Code: 0x80004005

I've done my home work, using Google, and found that it is often due to having 3 or 4 devices connected to an account with 50+ folders. My account is empty, no email or folder, and is not synced with any devices, I confirmed that on http://devices.live.com.

I'm out of option, any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thank you